# PowerShell: Difference between (ConvertTo-* | Set-Content) and (Export-*)?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I'm new to PowerShell, and trying to learn things the write way, I noticed in this case that I can export data in many different manners, what I want to ask about is this case,

```
Get-Process | ConvertTo-Csv | Set-Content -Path .\Process.txt
```

and :

```
 Get-Process | Export-Csv -Path .\Process.txt
```

Both exports the list of the processes into a CSV file on my desktop, and give the same result.

**The first one :**

Converts the processes to CSV first then it writes it onto the file.

**The second one :**

Exports the Processes directly to the file.

What's really the difference between the two cases, is there performance difference, time execution difference, or anything else I'm not aware of ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are pretty much the same. There shouldn't be any big difference when it comes to performance and time:

```
Measure-Command { Get-Process | ConvertTo-Csv | Set-Content -Path .\Process.txt }  

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 2
Milliseconds      : 880
Ticks             : 28801761
TotalDays         : 3,33353715277778E-05
TotalHours        : 0,000800048916666667
TotalMinutes      : 0,048002935
TotalSeconds      : 2,8801761
TotalMilliseconds : 2880,1761 

Measure-Command { Get-Process | Export-Csv -Path .\Process2.txt }

Days              : 0
Hours             : 0
Minutes           : 0
Seconds           : 2
Milliseconds      : 772
Ticks             : 27724661
TotalDays         : 3,20887280092593E-05
TotalHours        : 0,000770129472222222
TotalMinutes      : 0,0462077683333333
TotalSeconds      : 2,7724661
TotalMilliseconds : 2772,4661
```

This is because `Export-CSV` and `ConvertTo-CSV` run 90% of the same code. They share the same helper-class `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvHelper` to create the header and convert objects to csv. The only difference is that `ConvertTo-CSV` writes the CSV-object(string) to the pipeline using `WriteObject()`, while `Export-CSV` directly writes it to a file using a `StreamWriter`.

To find this yourself, you could look inside `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility.dll`. I won't be posting the code directly because I'm not sure if it's legal or not. :-)

If you need the CSV-output to be displayed or sent through a third-party API etc., then use `ConvertTo-CSV`. If you need the data stored in a CSV-file, then you should use `Export-CSV`.